# Why is x? = y valid syntax in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

I am surprised that this compiles

```
var x: Int? = 3
x? = 5
```

This seems to do the same thing as `x = 5`, but it doesn't make sense to me that this would be allowed at all. Would it ever behave differently (like if `x` was a different type, or if it were a property)?

Comment: it will behave differently when `x` is originally `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

When you make `x` optional

```
x? = 5
```

if x originally is `nil` then the line won't run , otherwise it'll act as `x = 5`

Comment: I am trying to find a reference for this. Do you have any? Considering https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md was rejected.

Comment: Nitpick in the language but if `x` is `nil`, the "line" still runs. It's that the assignment isn't applied in that case.

Comment: @Sulthan i don't , it's a matter of  trial and error

Comment: never mind. I found a Swift a bug and through it a reference to a duplicate question :)

Comment: I can't think of a single use-case for this...

Comment: @rmaddy i guess it will be `nil = 5` which is away from referencing the x value , which will make the compiler consider it as line on the fly

Comment: @Max you can append `?` even for a var declared with `!`  , i guess it's the developer job to be aware , the compiler may not catch all possible ways , it's written with regular expressions which if passed then the line compiles even if it's weird